# Sequelize create model with object type

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Is this possible to create model with sequelize to look like:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    facebook: {
      id: DataTypes.STRING,
      token: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      name: DataTypes.STRING
    },
})
```

Idea is: When i will get user data from DB i would like to see 
User: {
  facebook: {
    id,
    token,
    ...
  }
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Either

1. you make `User.facebook` a `DataType.JSON` field (which is supported by postgresql only)
2. you create an Entity 'facebook', which is 1:1 related to User

Option i) is fine, but you don't get any support from sequelize to check integrity and validity if you make it a json field.

Answer (score 0):

Column dataType - TEXT save as JSON format
after find table - return json patse text

```js
PodPodMaterial.afterFind(async (material) => {
  if(material.length) {
    for(let mat in material) {
      try {
          material[mat].ez_kolvo = JSON.parse(material[mat].ez_kolvo)
      } catch(e) {console.error(e)}
    }
  } else {
    try {
        material.ez_kolvo = JSON.stringify(material.ez_kolvo)
    }catch(e) {console.error(e)}
  }

  return material
})
```